# How to customize error handling in smarty?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, smarty, smarty3

Hi guys I wanted to customize my error handling... here's the scenario

1. Define in php controller
   Code:

   ```
   $this->CI->smarty->assign('_setData', $set_data);
   ```
2. $set_data contains
   Code:

   ```
   Array
   (
       [facebook] => https://facebook.com/ <---- this will be removed i
       [instagram] => https://instagram.com/
       [twitter] => https://twitter.com/
   )
   ```
3. code in html

Code:

```
{$_setData.facebook}
```

5. I receive an error

Code:

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: facebook
Filename: templates_c/5125124f1e59f2258a491707dcd0a86cf434db62_0.file.home_template.html.php
Line Number: 94
Backtrace:.......
```

5.I am aware that there is no facebook in the array but I wanted to adjust the error that if the variable (ex. facebook) is not defined in the controller the smarty code (ex. {$_setData.facebook}) will just display null/empty/0.

How can I make this happen in smarty? Is this possible to adjust the smarty?

Let me know if you have question or clarifications to my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can change smarty error reporting level in your php file and exclude notices (or any other notifications / errors in the template) with:

```
$smarty->error_reporting = error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE;
```

you can also use the default modifier inside the template:

```
{$_setData.facebook|default:''}
```